# Indicação de plugin para busca no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, algoritmo-de-busca, plugin, plugin-wordpress

Estou montando um projeto e preciso de uma indicação de plugin para eu criar uma busca parecida com essa, desse site:

http://www.fqmfarma.com.br/produtos

Onde o conteúdo é separado com letras, em ordem alfabética. Eu até poderia criar TABs, conseguiria um resultado parecido, mas observem que existe um FILTRO abaixo do texto **PRODUTOS >> FQM Farma**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O [A-Z Listing](https://codecanyon.net/item/dw-glossary-wordpress-plugin/) faz isso, inclusive através de shortcodes você consegue montar tua estrutura com ordem alfabética e ainda acrescentar os filtros desejados.

Outra alternativa, porém paga, é o [DW Glossary](https://codecanyon.net/item/dw-glossary-wordpress-plugin/).

Comment: Obrigado, o DW Glossary é perfeito

Comment: Fico feliz em ajudar. :) Grande abraço!